# Did Malfoy create the "Potter Stinks" badge?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Draco Malfoy taunts Harry with a badge that simultaneously supports Cedric Diggory and flashes "Potter Stinks":

> When he and Hermione arrived at Snape's dungeon after lunch, they
>   found the Slytherins waiting outside, each and every one of them
>   wearing a large badge on the front of his or her robes. For one wild
>   moment Harry thought they were S.P.E.W. badges - then he saw that they
>   all bore the same message, in luminous red letters that burnt brightly
>   in the dimly lit underground passage:
>
> Support CEDRIC DIGGORY - The REAL Hogwarts Champion!
>
> "Like them, Potter?" said Malfoy loudly as Harry approached. "And this
>   isn't all they do - look!"
>
> He pressed his badge into his chest, and the message upon it vanished,
>   to be replaced by another one, which glowed green:
>
> POTTER STINKS
>   ....
>
> **"Want one, Granger?", said Malfoy, "I've got loads."**

Malfoy tells Hermione he has a lot of them for distribution.

**Where did Malfoy get the badges? Did he create them, or modify existing Hufflepuff 'Digory' badges to add the pejorative against Potter?**

Comment: The badges were pro-Hufflepuff and many people stopped wearing them when Cedric told them not to, both of which imply a Hufflepuff origin. The *Potter stinks* line and the fact that Slytherins wore them first suggest Malfoy, though. Evidence inconclusive in my book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, he made them.

Within the books it's not explicitly stated whether Malfoy made the badges or whether he was simply enthusiastic in distributing them to his friends but in some of the later "Writings by JK Rowling" we learn that he did indeed make them himself.

> *Draco resorted to many different dirty tactics in his perpetual quest to get under Harry’s skin, or discredit him in the eyes of others including, but not limited to, telling lies about him to the press, **manufacturing insulting badges to wear about him**, attempting to curse him from behind, and dressing up as one of the Dementors*
>
> <sub><sup>[Draco Malfoy By J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/draco-malfoy)</sup></sub>

---

Moving down the canon scale, the Pottermore articles about '*Malfoy's best zingers'* state that he "organised" the badges and speculates about how he "mass produced" them.

> *Draco Malfoy was a total nightmare at Hogwarts: he was awful to
> Muggle-borns, mean about people less well-off than his unattainably
> rich family and annoyed Harry every chance he got. **Like that time he
> organised those 'Potter Stinks' badges.** Slow clap, Malfoy.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The worst Draco Malfoy burns of all time](https://www.pottermore.com/features/the-worst-draco-malfoy-burns-of-all-time)</sup></sub>

and

> **The time he mass-produced ‘Potter Stinks’ badges**
>
> *Draco clearly looks down on Hufflepuffs (he insulted the entire house
> the first time he met Harry), so the only reason he supported Cedric
> Diggory in the Triwizard Tournament is because he hated Harry that
> much. The ‘Potter Stinks’ badges were an iconic Draco move, firstly
> because he really is the sort of person who thinks badges are some
> kind of epic burn, and secondly because there's a possibility that
> Draco sat in his dorm room in his free time carefully making loads of
> magical badges. Imagine him, sat on his bed, bleakly drawing the name
> of his worst enemy over and over again. Who'd have thought he was that
> creative?*
>
> <sup>[Every time Draco Malfoy was just too Draco](https://www.pottermore.com/features/every-time-draco-malfoy-was-just-too-draco)</sup>

Comment: Do those sorts of Buzzfeedesc Pottermore articles even make any claim to be canonical? It's a good find, nonetheless.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - I think they're above actual buzzfeed articles. But not by much. I've literally no idea how (or if) they quality-check their articles.